# Why does 20130708 < "" return true in Python?

Tags: python, string

```
>>> 20130708 < ''
True
>>> 20130708 > ''
False
```

I am not sure what the explanation for this is.  [The wikipedia article on lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) says that

> u < v if u is a prefix of v

Since "" is a prefix of "20130708", I would expect "20130708" < "" to be false.

Comment: Sorry everybody this is the worst question on StackOverflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question title doesn't match your code. You're not comparing `"20130708"` with `""`, you're comparing `20130708` with `""` - ie an integer, with an empty string.

It's a peculiarity of Python 2 that integers always compare less than strings. In Python 3, this is fixed, and that code raises `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`.

Comment: Wow, yep, this was a stupid question.  I should just start going to sleep on Sunday and waking up Tuesday morning.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes here:

```
>>> "20130708" < ""
False
```

What you are doing is comparing `ints` to `str`, which are [rich comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).  So any `int` is "smaller" than any `str`.

Comment: "Rich comparison" does not refer to comparing objects of different types; it means that the several new comparison methods (`__lt__()`, `__ge__()`, etc.) are used instead of the older single-method `__cmp__()`.